# Faker imges not displaying properly

Tags: php, html, laravel, image, faker

I can't display properly my default faker images, but it works fine when it comes to uploaded images.
here is my **UserFactory.php**

```
$factory->define(App\Product::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
     'category_id' =>Category::all()->random()->id,
     'product_name' => $name =$faker->word,
     'product_code'=> $faker->word,
     'product_color'=> $faker->colorName,
     'image'=>'fake_avatar/p6.jpg',
     'feature_item'=>rand(0,1),
     'status'=>rand(0,1),
    ];
});
```

My seeder **DatabaseSeeder.php**

```
public function run()
    {  
  factory('App\Product',20)->create();
        
    }
}
```

My faker image location **public->fake_avatar->p6.jpg**
uploaded images location:
**public->images->backend_images->products->small**

This is what happens when I try to use one of my default images:

[image: Faker images not displaying properly]

And this is what happens when I try uploading some custom image to it:

[image: My uploads image displaying properly]

**i use this code for view product image**

```
    <td>
 <img src="{{ asset('images/backend_images/products/small/'.$product->image) }}">

 </td>
```

Can anyone help me to display faker images properly and when I uploads an image it also comes properly too.

Comment: Where is the `fake_avatar/p6.jpg` located at? 

Is it also inside the `images/backend_images/products/small/` path?

Comment: What have oyu tried to debug the problem? Why not check for the location difference between both scenarios, and put some explanation about this in your question by editing it?

Answer (score 0):

Offhand, I don't see a reason why your code shouldn't work.

If you use your browser developer console to inspect the area where an image should appear and doesn't, what do you see? What is the `src` value of the `img` attribute, assuming that's what's there?

If you view the developer console Network tab, are you seeing requests for images that are receiving 404 or similar responses?